# Save with "Retry as Sudo" using keyboard commands

Tags: visual-studio-code

Anytime I try to save a file (using Ctrl+S) that requires elevated permissions, I get the popup with the button to "Retry as Sudo". This is fine, but there does not seem to be any way to select "Retry as Sudo" using the keyboard. I have to use the mouse to actually click the "Retry as Sudo" button. I have tried tabbing, but cannot seem to select this button without using the mouse. Does anyone know if there is anyway to save a file as sudo without using the mouse?

Comment: opening the file in vs code with sudo command will solve the problem. `sudo code file.txt`

Comment: FYI I just created a feature request in VSCodes GitHub repo since I'm looking for the exact same thing: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90661

Comment: FYI: I just created [another feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/114195) to open the system prompt automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90661#issuecomment-586422989:

- Create keyboard shortcut for command `notifications.focusToasts`

When the `Retry as Sudo` toaster appears you can now:

- Press the assigned shortcut
- Press `Tab`
- Press `Enter`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to include an example to complement the other answers.

To add a keybinding open the command pallet:

ctl+shift+p Windows

cmd+shift+p MacOS

Search for `>Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` and press enter.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization

Below is an example that you can copy and paste as is into the json document. If there are no existing custom bindings just place it in between the [ ] brackets. If there are existing bindings (denoted by { } brackets) make sure you use a comma to separate them.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+l",
    "command": "notifications.focusToasts",
}
```

To be clear you will need to first save to bring up the "save as sudo" notification. *Then* you press the hotkey combination (which focuses the notification), then press TAB to highlight the "save as sudo" button, then press Enter to save.

It's not ideal, but it works.